# How to access logs using sed that is in a remote server using ssh?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, sed, echo

I'm trying to make use of `sed` command giving it a regex expression to filter out logs that falls under the given time stamp. I'm able to achieve it if the logs files are present in the same server where my script execute. This worked for me -

```
sed -n '/2018-01-07 19/,/2018-01-07 22:1[4-9]/p' /var/opt/xyz/Logs/ErrorLog_2.txt`.
```

This command filters out logs that matched the given regex expression. But complexity arises when the log files are in a remote server. I tried running this command -

```
ssh dbsrd3511.uhc.com `sed -n '/2018-01-07 19/,/2018-01-07
22:1[4-9]/p' /var/opt/xyz/Logs/ErrorLog_2.txt
```

But it throws error

```
 ksh: 2018-01-07:not found
```

However this works well when i add `echo` before `sed` like this -

```
ssh dbsrd3511.uhc.com echo `sed -n '/2018-01-07 19/,/2018-01-07 22:1[4-9]/p' /var/opt/xyz/Logs/ErrorLog_2.txt`
```

But echo concatenates everything. The output looks something like this -

```
40:09.146 Info: Deleted 13 MB at 1037 MB/sec /var/opt/MarkLogic/Forests/Meters/00002786 2018-01-07 21:40:09.148 Info: Deleted 9 MB at 3366 MB/sec /var/opt/MarkLogic/Forests/Meters/00002785 2018-01-07 21:52:00.893 Info: Saving /var/opt/MarkLogic/Forests/Meters/00002787 2018-01-07 21:52:02.039 Info: Saved 9 MB in 1 sec at 8 MB/sec to /var/opt/MarkLogic/Forests/Meters/00002787 2018-01-07 21:52:02.062 Info: Merging 73 MB from /var/opt/MarkLogic/Forests/Meters/00002783, /var/opt/MarkLogic/Forests/Meters/00002788, and /var/opt/MarkLogic/Forests/Meters/00002787 to /var/opt/MarkLogic/Forests/Meters/0000278a, timestamp=15153829212255230 2018-01-07 21:52:11.668 Info: Merged 71 MB in 10 sec at 7 MB/sec to /var/opt/MarkLogic/Forests/Meters/0000278a 2018-01-07 21:52:14.065 Info: Deleted 52 MB at 3235 MB/sec /var/opt/MarkLogic/Forests/Meters/00002783 2018-01-07 21:52:14.088 Info: Deleted 17 MB at 721 MB/sec /var/opt/MarkLogic/Forests/Meters/00002788 2018-01-07 21:52:14.105 Info: De
```

I'm unable to distinguish change of line. Is there a way I could the proper result ?

Ok! So far I'm able to run this command `ssh dbsrd3511.uhc.com 'sed -n "/2018-01-07 21/,/2018-01-07 22:1[4-9]/p" /var/opt/MarkLogic/Logs/ErrorLog_3.txt'` but the problem is these are hardcoded values. Actually, the dates and log files are stored in variables, so I'm receiving error when executing this command -  `ssh dbsrd3511.uhc.com 'sed -n "$dateRange" $error_log_file_name'`. It hangs while connecting to remote server. It doesn't return any output, just hangs while connecting to the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Ohk! This worked for me finally.

```
ssh dbsrd3511.uhc.com "sed -n '$dateRange' $error_log_file_name
```

This also worked for me -

```
ssh dbsrd3511.uhc.com "sed -n '/2018-01-07 21/,/2018-01-07 22:1[4-9]/p' /var/opt/MarkLogic/Logs/ErrorLog_3.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might wish to use the `-t` option with `ssh`. The manpage says

```
-t      Force pseudo-terminal allocation.  This can be used to execute
        arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be
        very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t
        options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.
```

In your case it should be something like

```
ssh -t dbsrd3511.uhc.com 'sed -n "/2018-01-07 19/,/2018-01-07 22:1[4-9]/p"
/var/opt/xyz/Logs/ErrorLog_2.txt'
```

<sup>**Note:** See how the quotes are used - Single quotes as a wrapper and double quotes for `sed` command</sup>

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the quoting and escaping nightmares, you could simply do this:

```
ssh -t dbsrd3511.uhc.com cat /var/opt/xyz/Logs/ErrorLog_2.txt | sed -n '/2018-01-07 19/,/2018-01-07 22:1[4-9]/p'
```

That runs the `sed` process on your local system, instead of remotely.

The (probably negligible) downside is that the entire log file is transferred through your `ssh` channel, but if it's not huge (i.e. gigabytes and beyond), that should not be a major concern.

Comment: this file can be in tera bytes.

Answer (score 0):

In version 9 there is a REST endpoint which can retrieve log files from any server in a cluster, searched by any combination of date range and regex.
No need to 'ssh' into the remote server, access to ML on any node in the cluster is sufficient.